# Unable to load dynamic data into ui-grid dropdownlist using custom template(Dropdown data was an asynchronous)

Tags: angularjs, drop-down-menu, upgrade, angular-ui-grid, ng-grid

I unable to load dropdown values dynamically while using custom template.
this is a generic template so that I can use any where in my application.

I have recently updated nggrid to ui-grid, and I am using custom templates for editing the grid row...
unfortunately after updating ui-grid from ngGrid everything working fine except dropdown list.

Controller.js

```
 vm.lov = {};
 LovService.getCurrencies().then(function (data) {
      vm.lov.Currency = data;
   });

//Single column code in a grid
  {
    name: 'Currency',
    editableCellTemplate: 'ui-grid/dropdownEditor',
    editDropdownIdLabel: 'Id', 
    editDropdownValueLabel: 'Id',
    editDropdownOptionsArray: vm.lov.Currency
   },
```

dropdownEditor template

```html
<select ng-class="'colt' + col.uid" ui-grid-edit-dropdown ng-model="MODEL_COL_FIELD" ng-options="field as field for field in editDropdownOptionsArray"></select>
```

I want to load items when user click on cell.
This happened when I have updated from nggrid to ui-grid,
I have spent lot of hours for finding the solutions but I can't,
I hope stackoverflow is perfect for my to ask a question...
Thanks in advance...